# Check all errors raised by Parsleyjs

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a form I'm validating using Parsley.js that was working before, but now won't allow submission of the form, though there's no explanation of why form submission is failing (though I've verified it's Parsley that's preventing submission). Two questions:

(1) I suspect that Parsley validations are failing on a field that's hidden or just not displaying its error messages for some reason. Is there a way to just log all the Parsley validation failures in the console?

(2) Is there a way to disable Parsley from preventing form submission, while still keeping alive Parsley's features for providing "live" validation feedback on keypress, etc.?

---

The code:

Here's a sample input div with the parsley validation info, as it's being rendered:

```
<input class="parsley-validated parsley-error" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="keyup change keypress" id="order_delivery_address" name="order[delivery_address]" placeholder="Address" type="text" value="" data-parsley-id="8942">
```

I initialize Parsley like this:

```
$('#new_order').parsley()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Parsley fields results are stored in `validationResult`, for each field. Fields are stored in `fields`.

```
var failingFields = [],
  parsleyForm = $('#new_order').parsley();

for (var i = 0; i < parsleyForm.fields.length; i++)
  if (true !== parsleyForm.fields[i].validationResult && parsleyForm.fields[i].validationResult.length)
    failingFields.push(parsleyForm.fields[i].$element);
```

2) To prevent Parsley from preventing form submission, you'd have to do `$('#new_order).off('submit.Parsley')`

Answer (score 1):

Code would be helpful, but to elaborate on part 2 you can do this..

```
$('form').off('submit.parsleyForm');
```

... after the `$('form').parsley(...)` initialisation call.

Just make sure you call `$('form').parsley('validate')` when you want to validate the form.

Comment: $('form').off('submit.parsleyForm'); isn't doing the trick for me, unfortunately. I've edited my question with code.

Comment: what version of parsley are you using?

Comment: also you need to use the same element that you initialised parsley with. In your case it would be `$('#new_order').off('submit.parsleyForm')`

Comment: Make sure you all it after `$('#new_order').parsley()`

Comment: Right, I tried it with the right element just pasted your example in my comment. I'm using v 2.0.0.

Comment: You can also try $('#new_order').off('submit') but make sure you do all of this before adding any of you own event handlers. Otherwise you will remove your own handlers if you have them. Failing that, you may have to wait until someone that has dealt with parsley v2 comes up with a better suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but found out something new: the failed submission problem seems to be limited to Chrome.